# How to upgrade Docker (to 1.10.0) on CentOS7?

Tags: docker, centos7

Docker 1.8.2-10.el7.centos was installed and was able to run on CentOS7.

In order to upgrade docker [this post](https://media-glass.es/2014/11/02/latest-docker-centos7/) was read and the following commands were issued:

- `curl -L https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest > /usr/bin/docker; chmod +x /usr/bin/docker`
- `curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.service > /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`
- `curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.socket > /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket`

**Problem**

When docker is started:

```
systemctl start docker
```

it seems to hang and /var/log/messages indicates that:

```
Feb 11 00:22:01 localhost systemd: Device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f00f4f0a\x2dba57\x2d468b\x2dba82\x2d72f1bb087bbb.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths /sys/devices/virtual/block/loop0 and /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-6
Feb 11 00:22:05 localhost docker: time="2016-02-11T00:22:05.977110830+01:00" level=info msg="calculated checksum for layer 26de6fe292b2275378ce421742105813ee98fb49a5e0e45c1fd89e20eedc2c31: sha256:0c42efc496d9944258fb38ccfa64f53c32433a24daa3ad64144e48c5deb1c78c"
Feb 11 00:22:06 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-8): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Feb 11 00:22:06 localhost systemd-udevd: conflicting device node '/dev/mapper/docker-253:0-68595821-51009a2811797c49222fd5f9cb9e38fbe4fca9cf2a7fcfb1151d34c0b545a42a' found, link to '/dev/dm-8' will not be created
Feb 11 00:22:06 localhost systemd: Device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f00f4f0a\x2dba57\x2d468b\x2dba82\x2d72f1bb087bbb.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths /sys/devices/virtual/block/loop0 and /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-8
```

**Discussion**

1. The strange thing is that the binary has been upgraded:

   [root@localhost]# docker -v
   Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108

but the service cannot be started.

2. Although 1.10.0 cannot start on CentOS7, docker 1.9.0 is able to start: `curl -L https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.9.0 > /usr/bin/docker; chmod +x /usr/bin/docker`

**Question**

How to upgrade Docker to 1.10.0 on CentOS7?

Comment: Wait for it to be packaged? They do try to maintain at least a modicum of stability in EPEL. If you really want to track the latest Docker, try Fedora instead of CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## docker's default storage driver might have changed.

I had the same problem and today I was succeded to start docker 1.10 finally. My problem was the docker's starting command. It seemed that I had used the docker with `devicemapper` storage driver and docker 1.10 driver was not the same.

Here is what I tried.

#### 1. Delete network files.

When I gave up upgrading docker 1.10 once and downgraded it 1.10 to 1.9, 1.9 wouldn't start. It started after I deleted these files. This may not effect your problem, but I decided that I delete them before upgrade docker from now on.

```
mkdir /var-lib-docker-network-files  
mv /var/lib/docker/network/files/* /var-lib-docker-network-files
```

#### 2. Overwrite `ExecStart` as your customized command.

You can see the default start command in here;

```
vi /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Mine was completely same with the official repository's.

ttps://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.service

It should be like this;

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
```

This command didn't work for me. So I made a file which overrided the command as a wrapping conf file here;

```
vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf 

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -s devicemapper -H fd://
```

#### 3. Reload and Start

Make sure to reload systemd before start docker.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
service docker start
```

#### FYI, this command will remove all docker images.

I saw an another ExecStart line at [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20376).

```
vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf 

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=docker daemon -D -s overlay
```

Although this worked and made docker 1.10 started, my all of docker images has disappeared. I was very annoyed due to `docker images` returned nothing.
But I still had a lot of real image files in `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/` so I thought this command reffered a strange directory. Then I got the answer, it's `devicemapper`.

#### Official Document

You can see the details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/). We might have to learn about the daemon.

Answer (score 1):

## docker 1.10 migration needs too much time

Your docker 1.10 will launch if you can wait for a day after restart it.

> All your current images, tags and containers are automatically migrated to the new foundation the first time you start Docker Engine 1.10. Before loading your container, the daemon will calculate all needed checksums for your current data, and after it has completed, all your images and tags will have brand new secure IDs.
>
> While this is simple operation, calculating SHA256 checksums for your files can take time if you have lots of image data. On average you should assume that migrator can process data at a speed of 100MB/s. During this time your Docker daemon won’t be ready to respond to requests.

Please see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/migration/).